# Requisição GET com AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Boa tarde estou tentando realizar uma requisição Get com AngularJs mas não recebo nenhuma resposta e o único console.log que executa é o ultimo que ja esta do lado de fora da requisição;

```
        angular.module("listaTelefonica").controller("listaTelefonicaCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.contatos = [];
       var carregarContatos = function(){
          $http({method:'GET',url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccLAsEcOSq?indent=1'}).then(function(response){
            console.log("conexão foi realizada") 
            console.log(response.data);

          }).catch(
             console.log("falha na conexão")
          );
          console.log("falha na conexão")
       };
       console.log("falha na conexão")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccLAsEcOSq?indent=1';
var carregarContatos = function(){
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        console.log("conexão foi realizada") 
        console.log(response.data);

      }).catch(
         console.log("falha na conexão")
      );
      console.log("falha na conexão")
   };
   console.log("falha na conexão")
```

Answer (score 0):

Se voce tiver passando seu codigo por algum transpilador, como Babel, ou minificador, voce deve usar sempre os servicos declarados na criacao do controller.

e voce esqueceu, que primeiro vem o nome do controller, e depois vem o array de servicos. faltou o "**[**" "**]**"

```js
angular.module("listaTelefonica").controller("listaTelefonicaCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

//Seu codigo aqui

}]);
```